# Copy image from webbrowser to clipboard

Tags: vb.net, image, browser, clipboard, captcha

I need to copy an image from a webbrowser control to my clipboard, because the image changes on every reload, and I tried to get the "src"-attribute and changing my picturebox.imagelocation to that, but the image on the picturebox differed from the picture on the webbrowser control.

I'm trying to automate a web service, and it requires a captcha to be filled out, and it changes every time the page is loaded, that's why I need to get the one that is currently displayed.

Comment: More detail on HOW you're doing it currently. Also you might have to ditch the web browser control.

Comment: @Jeremy Child
This is how I would be doing it, if it would had worked, note that "Captcha" is a form with a picturebox control on it.


 For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")
  If element.GetAttribute("id") = "siimage" Then
   Captcha.PictureBox1.ImageLocation = element.GetAttribute("src")
  End If
 Next


And what do you mean by "ditch" the webbrowser control? I need it for the process to work.

Comment: I just dislike the `WebBrowser` control, don't mind me.

Comment: @user2230481 You might want to move that code from your comment to the question. It'll make it easier to read.

Comment: The webbrowser control is required for my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Windows Forms (need to change the way to get document if you use WPF) and the user did not block clipboard access in IE zone settings

```
Dim doc As IHTMLDocument2 = DirectCast(webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument, IHTMLDocument2)
Dim body As IHTMLElement2 = DirectCast(doc.body, IHTMLElement2)
Dim imgRange As IHTMLControlRange = DirectCast(body.createControlRange(), IHTMLControlRange)
Dim image As IHTMLControlElement = DirectCast(DirectCast(doc, IHTMLDocument3).getElementById(sImgID), IHTMLControlElement)
imgRange.add(image)
imgRange.execCommand("Copy", False, Nothing)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm talking about, finally somebody who understands.

Comment: I enabled clipboard access and implemented this method in my code, but it still does not copy the image.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

For each element by tag 'img'. Get the 'src' attribute. Fire up an instance of `HttpWebRequest` or use `WebClient.DownloadFile` for the source.

You will need to do some trickery determining where the source is in relation to the url. For instance the src could be '/img/pony.jpg', in which case you'll need to get the url's root from the `WebBrowser` control to make it 'http://mylittle.com/img/pony.jpg'.

Comment: Seeing as the image changes on every request, this is useless, I need to actually use the WebBrowser1.Document.ExecCommand to be able to successfully get the right image.